# How to fetch the data from the API and store into a variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to fetch some data from the API and the data I need to store the data in a variable.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? What kind of data, which API etc. Otherwise noone could help you.

Comment: if you need fetch data, use https://pub.dev/packages/http or https://pub.dev/packages/dio  packages.  Please provide a more details about what kind data do you need  store in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to create an object where you want to put your json data.
more likely you use http package for retrieving data from api then store it in your created object. usually api data formatted as json format, in that case you use dart:convert for Serializing JSON. For displaying the output you're about to use the getter to retrieve the data from your object.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
      dio: ^4.0.6
```

//Code in dart file

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
void getHttp() async {
  try {
    var response = await Dio().get('http://www.google.com');
    print(response);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: How to store the response data into a variable.